# Changing img src via JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, laravel-5.3

I got this HTML image item:

```
<img class="profile-photo img-responsive img-circle" id="imagen_perfil_banner" src="{{ asset('admin/img/profile1.jpg') }}" >
```

Then I got the JS that changes the `src` attribute of the image like this:

```
document.getElementById("imagen_perfil_banner").src = info[13];
```

The `info[13]` variable has the next information:

```
{{ asset('admin/img/1.jpg') }}
```

When tha page loads, it just doesn't show the image that I send via JS, but when I put the image directly on the image `src` attribute, it loads just fine.

Comment: What is the eventual text that is sent to the `src` attribute? what data representation is this `{{ asset('admin/img/1.jpg') }}`?

Comment: take note that javascript is in the client side, `{{ asset('admin/img/1.jpg') }}` must be processed first in the backend before it will be sent to the client/browser. So assigning `{{ asset('admin/img/1.jpg') }}` via javascript and expecting it to pull the image asset from the backend is impossible since browser will treat it as a string

Comment: Open devtools and read what error message says.

Comment: @kennasoft `{{ asset('admin/img/1.jpg') }}` seems to be some sort of javascript that needs to be pre-processed, which will have the value of the return of `asset('admin/img/1.jpg')` call

Comment: We already notice you're using some sort of pre-processor because of those {{ }} you have on your scr attribute. We just need to know which javascript framework you're using to do that?

Comment: @kennasoft the html file is a blade file that works with laravel. The code that i'm sending to the src is: {{ asset('admin/img/1.jpg') }} that should work, because if I just put the same code directly to the src attribute of the image, the image just show normally

Comment: @CarlosJaramilloCorrales brother, you can't do that. As I said above, {{}} belongs to laravel or the backend which simply means, that it needs to be parsed or processed by laravel first. Backend is different from frontend. If your way is injecting {{}} via javascript where it will be parsed in the browser and laravel at that time is done parsing, hence, it won't going to work. Know the process brother.

Comment: would be helpful to see more code but did you try var newAsset = '{{ asset('admin/img/1.jpg') }}';  Then document.getElementById("imagen_perfil_banner").src = newAsset

Comment: @Roljhon I know how you feel!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this:

```
var image = document.getElementById("imagen_perfil_banner")
image.src=info[13];
```

You firstly have to save the image in a variable. I hope it helps. Good luck.

Comment: it does the same thing my friend.

Comment: Only trying to help :)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your are using [Angular](https://angular.io/) or some similar templating engine like [handelbars.js](http://handlebarsjs.com/) maybe Laravel.

This should work as expected if info[13] is a valid image url:

```
document.getElementById("imagen_perfil_banner").src = info[13];
```

The call **{{ asset('admin/img/1.jpg') }}** is not yet a valid url. You first have to process this as mentioned in the comments above to get the absolute url path of the asset.

You can change an image on the client side like this:

https://jsfiddle.net/0e8u38oo/

Hope this helps :)